# Chrome Extension: Difference between "permissions" and "matches" (match patterns)

Tags: google-chrome-extension, permissions, manifest, content-script

I am trying to understand, what is the difference between:

```
  "permissions": [
    "*.google.com"
  ],
```

and

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["*.google.com"]
    }
  ]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**1. Permissions for domains**

Web pages can not make Cross-Origin XMLHttpRequest (AJAX), but extensions can. Adding the domain in permissions will allow you to do ajax requests to the specified domain from your content scripts.

**2. Matches**

Content scripts work inside loaded pages. With `matches` you are able to specify inside which pages you want to inject your content scripts.

Example: I want to fetch weather data from openweathermap.org, and present the data only on google.com pages.

```
"permissions": [
  "http://api.openweathermap.org/*"
],
"content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": ["https://*.google.com/*"],
    "js": ["js/content.js"]
  }
]
```

Comment: How would this relate to "activeTab"? I have a button that a user should be able to click, which will then run a script on the current (any) page and send and retrieve info from an API endpoint. I don't want any access to anything without the click. The API endpoint is provided by the user in an options page. Is permissions = "activeTab" and matches = <all_urls> the most restrictive way to do this?